# Randomly Generate Orthogonal 3x3 Matrix

Tags: c#, matrix, orthogonal, siemens-nx

I'm looking to do some complex part analysis within Seimens NX. I'm looking to implement the double caliper method of measuring a model in order to find the minimum possible box that it could possibly fit into(for machining purposes). I've got all of my measurement code in place, but I am completely baffled by the idea of a construct that can randomly output normalized 3x3 vectors for use as coordinate systems. The part is measured with respect to this coordinate system, so each coordinate system gives a unique "minimum part envelope". Once analyzed, the smallest envelope is selected and displayed.

```
this is the type of vector I am talking about:
1 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 1

numbers can be any value between -1 and 1, with decimals not only being accepted but pretty much required.
```

and no, this isn't my homework. More of an individual pursuit in my free time at work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you apply a rotation matrix to an already orthogonal matrix, then the result should also be orthogonal.

So you can redefine your problem as applying a random rotation matrix to the identity matrix.

Perhaps do one random rotation matrix for each axis (x,y,z) and then apply the matrices themselves in a random order?

Comment: This could actually be a step in the right direction. I do have access to the absolute coordinate system of the part itself, so a transform is completely acceptable. Hell, I believe there are already methods available for just that. I spent to much timer pouring over how to do this I overlooked the most obvious answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind to consider only a special subset of the orthogonal matrices, there is an easier way to achieve this, which is to take advantage of the [Rodrigues' rotation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula) to generate [rotation matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) (which has an additional constraint that its determinant is equal to 1).

[image: Image of the Rodrigues' rotation formula]

[image: Image of the bracket notation]

With this, you only need to generate a random 3x1 unit vector (as the rotation axis) and specify a rotation angle. This formula will transform them into a valid rotation matrix.

MATLAB example:

```
function R = rot(w, theta)
  bw = [0, -w(3), w(2); w(3), 0, -w(1); -w(2), w(1), 0];
  R = eye(3) + sin(theta)*bw + (1-cos(theta))*bw*bw;
end

w = rand(3,1)
w = w/norm(w)
R = rot(w, 3.14)
```

C++ example:

```
// w: the unit vector indicating the rotation axis
// theta: the rotation angle in radian
Eigen::Matrix3d MatrixExp3 (Eigen::Vector3d w, float theta){
  Eigen::Matrix3d bw, R;
  bw << 0, -w(2), w(1), w(2), 0, -w(0), -w(1), w(0), 0;
  R << Eigen::Matrix3d::Identity() + std::sin(theta)*bw + (1-std::cos(theta))*bw*bw;
  return R;
}

int main() {
  std::srand((unsigned int) time(0));
  Eigen::Vector3d w = Eigen::Vector3d::Random();
  Eigen::Matrix3d R = MatrixExp3(w.normalized(), 3.14f);
  std::cout << R << std::endl;
}
```